# Riemannian integrability

Tags: integration

Suppose for $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$, $|f(x)|$ is Riemannian integrable on the interval $[a,b]$. If $f(x)$ is the derivative of $F(x)$ ,that is, $F'(x)=f(x), \forall x \in [a,b]$.

Prove: $f(x)$ is Riemannian integrable on the interval $[a,b]$ too.
In this situation I know that the image of $f(x)$, $f([a,b])$ has intermediate property, so $f([a,b])$ is connected. $|f|$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ almost everywhere, but I don't know what to do next. Hope someone can help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We consider all point where $\vert f\vert$ is continuous.
For any point $x$ such that $f(x)=0$, we note that $\vert \vert f(x)\vert -0\vert <\epsilon \Leftrightarrow \vert f(x) -0\vert <\epsilon$, which indicates $f$ is continuous.
For other points, without loss of generality, we suppose $f(x_0)>0$. Thus $\exists \epsilon>0\,$ s.t. $$x\in U(x_0,\epsilon) \Rightarrow \vert\vert f(x)\vert-\vert f(x_0)\vert\vert<\frac{\vert f(x_0)\vert}{4},$$and then the intermediate property indicates $f=\vert f\vert$ holds in $U(x_0,\epsilon)$. We also have the continuity at $x$ now.